# Unable to read nested JSON object in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a JSON node called 'data' that has an id. I want to store the value of that id but I'm unable to do so with my current syntax and I'm getting an error saying it's undefined.

How should I change my code to make this work?

My code snippet:

```
const transfer_ID = data.items.id;
    console.log("This is the transfer tree obtained", data);
```

data:

```
{ entity: 'collection',
  count: 1,
  items: 
   [ { id: 'trf_Ary1cWasdfGmHAc',
       entity: 'transfer',
       source: 'pay_ASrxasdfetwhAFv',
       amount: 390000,
       currency: 'INR',
       amount_reversed: 0,
       notes: [],
       fees: 1151,
       tax: 176,
       on_hold: false,
       on_hold_until: null,
       recipient_settlement_id: null,
       created_at: 1530208843 } ] }
```

Comment: data.items[0].id;

Comment: Don't give up on your first try. If you had debugged with your log statement and inspect just what data.items gives you, you would've figure it out right away!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check following code snippet

```js
var data ={ entity: 'collection',
  count: 1,
  items: 
   [ { id: 'trf_Ary1cWasdfGmHAc',
       entity: 'transfer',
       source: 'pay_ASrxasdfetwhAFv',
       amount: 390000,
       currency: 'INR',
       amount_reversed: 0,
       notes: [],
       fees: 1151,
       tax: 176,
       on_hold: false,
       on_hold_until: null,
       recipient_settlement_id: null,
       created_at: 1530208843 } ] } 
       
   var id =  data.items[0].id;
   console.log(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read the object as `data.items.id` because `items` is an array. You have to access the specific index that you wish to get the ID for.

Example:
`const transfer_ID = data.items[0].id;`

You could get an array of ID's by iterating over the array and storing those ID's as needed.